# Arranging letters in a circle

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

1-In how many ways the letters : A-B-C-D-E-a-b-c-d-e can be arranged in a circle in a way that no lower and upper cases of the same letter are adjacent?

2-In how many ways they can be arranged if the location of upper case letters are predetermined?

For the second part i tried counting all possible ways and i got 13.

Is there a better way to count in the second part and how to solve part one?

Comment: which technique did you use to count them ? I think that $13$ is so small

Comment: @Bulbasaur You are right. I edited my question

Comment: 1 is a duplicate of b in [In how many ways you can sit n men and n women so that :](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1125114/318073) - tldr use inclusion-exclusion.